# Jersey rendering JAXB objects (from a webservice) with null values,

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jersey

Using Oracle Rightnow, Jersey 1.18,JAX-WS, JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.1

Im creating a REST interface to our Rightnow instance and Im hitting an issue with null values.

I access RightNow via JAX-WS , and have generated a static proxy with JAXB Objects. In the past Ive been able to simply return the JAXB object to Jersey and it gets rendered lovely.. However with Rightnow Im getting lots of extra (null) fields rendered.. On a different system (Oracle SalesCloud) these fields dont get rendered by default..

Also worth noting I dont return the raw List of Object (incidents is my example) but I wrap the list using my own class so I can put a @XmlRootElement annotation.

My wrapper looks like this

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) // tried this doesnt work
public class RESTIncidents {
    private List<Incident> incidents;
    public void setIncidents(List<Incident> incidents) {
    this.incidents = incidents;
    }
 }
```

and the result I get back is

```
{
    "incidents" : [
   {
       "Asset" : null, "AssignedTo" :  {
           "Account" : null, "StaffGroup" :  {
               "ID" :  {
                  "id" : 100885
              },"Name" : "B2CHousewares"
           },"ValidNullFields" : null
        },"BilledMinutes" : null, "Category" :  {
           "ID" :  {
               "id" : 124
           },"Parents" : [
           {
           .....
```

I looked at using the @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) annotation but that didnt appear to work, Im guessing its because it only affects this class. I could add it to all the JAXB Generated classes but i dont want to (in case I need to regenerate the classes)..

My alternative approach is to create a custom collection of classes for the data transfer but I thought this approach would save me time + code..

Any thoughts?

thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to suss it out..

I needed to create a custom Object Mapper and tell it not to render nulls, this worked for the JAXB objects which were generated for me..

Simply create a mapper class and ensure the @Provider tag is present

Also note my code is for Jersey 1.x, specifically 1.8

package myPackage;

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@Provider
public class CustomJSONObjectMapper implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    public CustomJSONObjectMapper() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("My object mapper init");
         objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
         // Force all conversions to be NON_NULL for JSON
         objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        System.out.println("My Object Mapper called");
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

And the result is

```
{
    "organization" : [
    {
        "id" :  {
            "id" : 68
        },"lookupName" : "AngieSoft", "createdTime" : 1412166303000, "updatedTime" : 1412166303000, "name" : "AngieSoft", "salesSettings" :  {
            "salesAccount" :  {
                "id" :  {
                    "id" : 2
                }
            },"totalRevenue" :  {
                "currency" :  {
                    "id" :  {
                        "id" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },"source" :  {
            "id" :  {
                "id" : 1002
            },"parents" : [
            {
                "id" :  {
                    "id" : 32002
                }
            }
]
        },"crmmodules" :  {
            "marketing" : true, "sales" : true, "service" : true
        }
    }
]
}
```